# capital gains on oversea property for non-resident of Canada

Tags: canada, non-resident, capital-gains-tax

I live overseas in Belize and have for over 5 years and other than my Canadian Passport I have no other ties to Canada.  I'm considering selling my house in Belize and with the proceeds from the sale move back to Canada.   Will I have to pay capital gains to Revenue Canada on the sale of my house in Belize ?